# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest'. when return

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Function written in JS, which is triggered by the Service Bus and generates files to Blob Storage. When I'm trying to return an HTTP result I'm receiving the error as below:

`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.categoryMessageConsumer. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest'.`

I don't know why the result is trying to be mapped to the HttpRequest object.

index.ts:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
...

const serviceBusTopicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function(context: Context, req: HttpRequest) {
    let categoryMessage: CategoryMessage = Object.assign(new CategoryMessage(), req);
    let messageValidationResult = await categoryMessage.validate();
    if(!messageValidationResult.isValid) {
        context.log.error(messageValidationResult.errors);
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: "Unexpected error"
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

function.json output binding:

```
...
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
...
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require('https');
module.exports = function (context, eventHubMessages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);
    
    eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {
        
        function callService(msg) {
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var options = {
                    host: process.env["HOST"],
                    port: process.env["PORT"],
                    path: process.env["PATH"],
                    method: process.env["WEBSERVICE_METHOD"],
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': process.env["WEBSERVICE_CONTENT_TYPE"],
                        'x-api-key' : process.env["WEBSERVICE_API_KEY"]
                    }
                };
                var response = '';
                const request = http.request(options, (res) => {
                    res.on('data', (d) => {
                        response += d;
                    })
    
                    res.on('end', (d) => {
                        context.res = {
                            body: response
                        };
                        resolve(response);
                    })
                });

                request.on('error', (error) => {
                    context.log.error(error);
                    reject(error);
                    context.done();
                })
                
                request.write(msg);
                request.end();

              });
              promise.then((response) => {
                context.log(`mensagge send: ${msg}`);
                context.log(`response: ${response}`);
                context.done();
            });
            
        }
        
        callService(message);
    });
};
```

It was my index.js

and now it is my function.js:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "eventHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "event-hub-name",
      "connection": "CONNECTION_EVENT_HUB",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "dataType": "string"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

and in the local.settings.json I declared all of the environment vars like HOST, PORT, CONNECTION_EVENT_HUB, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For us this was fixed by removing this binding from function.json:

```
{
 "type": "http",
 "direction": "out",
 "name": "res"
}
```

So the result is if you're running the function using a timingTrigger you'd have:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "index.js",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you move back to HTTP or other you need to fill out the bindings in full again and remove the reference to the timer trigger:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "index.js",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, your function is probably trying to create another object which it did not expect.

As you have mentioned the response variable name as `$return` and it is expecting that. Rather than this, code your function like below:

*function.json:*

```
{
    "disabled": false,    
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "function",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "res"
        }
    ]
}
```

*JS code:*

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
    context.log('Node.js HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri=%s', req.originalUrl);

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

For configuration options in `function.json`, you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#configuration) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#configuration).